# Run Stepper motor with more torque and smoothly

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, torque, stepper-driver

I have a stepper motor and its torque curve is below.

[image: torque curve]

I am trying to get more torque from the motor. Therefore, I decided to setup my driver to half step. I am using an Arduino for generate the pulses as below code.

```
void move() {
  if (micros() - lastStepTime >= stepDelay) {
    lastStepTime = micros();
    digitalWrite(STEP_DOWN, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(1000);
    digitalWrite(STEP_DOWN, LOW);
  }

}
```

I have used `delayMicroseconds(1000)` for get 1000PPS output.

Unfortunately, when I use this 1000PPS pulse rate, motor cannot run smoothly.

Greatly appreciate someone can give a solution for that.

Comment: Half-stepping the motor **reduces** torque, not increases it. Although it does help motor run smoothly. What is your stepper driver and how did you set it up for half-stepping? Does it work well at different pulse rates?

Comment: I cant use full step.So Im using half step.  Microstepping can run  the motor very smoothly as my experiance.
Im  using TB6560 driver.

Comment: Why are you using a variable delay followed by a fixed 1000 µs delay? Won't that give a variable pulse width?

Comment: @Transistor variable delay is between pulses, fixed is pulse length. Looks OK to me, except pulse length is way too long, 100 uS should be enough.

Comment: @Maple: Ahh, this is feeding pulses to an external driver and the step sequence is not generated in the micro. OK.

Comment: @NSiri I don't know why you "cannot use full step", unless you are trying to increase precision. The only way to get maximum torque from this driver is to configure switches for maximum running current and full step mode. Also, that delayMicroseconds() call does not define PPS, it only limits maximum possible rate. stepDelay is what changes PPS.

Comment: @Maple When I use 100uS motor cant rotate and it generates a noice kile a beep. what is the reason for that?

Comment: @Maple And also, when I reduce the delay(pulse length delay) torque also reduced.

Comment: The reason for this could be wrong stepDelay value. Another reason could be use of wrong data types and not handling timer overflow properly. Or thousand other issues. You did not show enough of you code to answer this. But if your motor generates any sound with 100 us pulse it means the controller _recognizes the pulse_, i.e. 100 us is enough.

Comment: Thanks @Maple. Anyway 1000uS is ok.It can get more torque suitable for my application. Do you know any other vibration reducing method without changing pulse width(1000uS)?

Comment: Torque has **absolutely nothing** to do with pulse width. You only need pulse long enough so driver can detect it as pulse. It is the delay between pulses that defines speed, or PPS. The torque depends on speed, but not much between 100 and 1000 PPS.

Comment: I have a little idea about different between pulse width and PPS. However I have no idea how it effect with the stepper driver.If you can give good resources for get a knowledge about that very appreciate.